# Is there a keyboard shortcut to repeat search backwards ('Find Previous') in Python IDLE?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, python-idle

Using IDLE (Python 3.x) in Windows, as is the case with many editors, `F3` works as a keyboard shortcut for the 'Find Again' command in Python IDLE (as well as the menu-indicated `<Ctrl>-G`, plus various combinations of `<Shift>`, `<Ctrl>` and `<Alt>` with `F3` or `G`). These all search forwards from the current location in the file.

From habit I often press `<Shift>-F3` to search backwards, especially after working in an editor that offers this feature. I have not found anything in the IDLE documentation about a 'Find Previous' feature other than the option to select the search direction in the Search Dialog.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for 'Find Previous' in Python IDLE?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Find-again uses the most resent settings in the search box.